# Failed to write .bat file for launching jupyter lab (jupyter notebook)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, jupyter-notebook, julia

I often use jupyterlab on my Windows 10 PC and I always launch it by typing

```
> julia
> using IJulia
> jupyterlab()
```

on a command-prompt.

It is bothersome typing this every time I use it, so I tried writing `.bat` file to automate this process like below:

[jupyterlab.bat]

```
echo "launching jupyterlab..."
julia
using IJulia
jupyterlab()
end
```

However, this command line stops when Julia launched, that mean cmd does not read `using IJulia` and `jupyterlab()`.

Why does this happen and how can I get through it?

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once `julia` is executed, you're no longer in command-line of Windows anymore. For example, `using IJulia` is intended to be typed into Julia REPL, not Windows command-line. The easier way is to pass the commands into Julia directly, try having this in your `.bat` file:

```
julia -e "using IJulia; jupyterlab()"
```

The `-e` (and other options) is explained here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/command-line-options/#command-line-options

Answer (score 1):

The `*.bat` command is execute in Windows command line that accepts only Windows commands not Julia commands and you have mixed both of them.

Rather than that you should use the `-e` parameter available when launching Julia.

Hence your `*.bat` file could be:

```
echo "launching jupyterlab..."
julia -e "using IJulia;jupyterlab()"
```